# Center a column of containers in flutter, crossAxis doesnt work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to center a column of containers that start vertically from the bottom, however i cant get them to horizontally center.

mainAxisAlignment works fine for putting them at the bottom, however crossAxis doesnt react at all.

[image]

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,


        children: <Widget>[

        SizedBox(height: 25,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container(color: Colors.red, width: 150, height: 80,),

        ]
    ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Ive also tried wrapping in Align with no luck.

(I'm using SizedBox to space them , don't know if thats the optimal way to do it.)

Comment: It is centered but your `Home` widget width is smaller than the window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your column width doesn't cover the whole screen.

[image]

You should wrap the Column with a Container having width: double.infinity. Like this :

```
     Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[....]
             )
          )
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `Column` with `Center` widget.

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 150,
              height: 80,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Column with a Container having width: double.infinity

```
 Scaffold(
    body: Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[....
```